# Go use of exec.Command on windows for noverify

Tags: windows, go

I want to use VKCOM/[noverify](https://github.com/VKCOM/noverify) to analyse code. Calling it from the command-line (windows dos shell) using this command works

```
 noverify.exe -exclude-checks arraySyntax,phpdocLint 
              -output result.txt 
              C:\Dev\PHP\ResourceSpace_9_0_13357\include
```

The trouble is that i am unable to pass arguments to `cmnd := exec.Command("noverify.exe", args)`

```
options := " -exclude-checks arraySyntax, PHPDoc"
pathToCode := "C:\\Dev\\PHP\\ResourceSpace_9_0_13357\\include"

// this works
cmnd := exec.Command("noverify.exe", pathToCode)


args := []string{options, pathToCode}
arg := strings.Join(args, "")
// passing options does not work
// cmnd := exec.Command("noverify.exe", arg)    

b, err := cmnd.CombinedOutput()
```

#### What have i tried

You can find [my source code in this gist](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/0c197b8ae8e231d4fdf4a879a60a186d) It seems that args are joined as a string seperated by `,` despite that the separator is empty above.

#### Questions

1. How to pass multiple arguments to `exec.Comman("yourFoo.exe", cmdArgs...)`
2. Why is my attempt not working on windows?

Comment: `-exclude-checks arraySyntax,phpdocLint` <--- these are 2 arguments, while you're passing them as a single string. `[]string{"-exclude-checks", "arraySyntax,phpdocLint"}`. And you don't need to `strings.Join` them after: arguments is a collection of strings and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options to pass arguments to exec.Command:

You can use multiple strings as arguments:

```
cmd := exec.Command("your-command", "arg1", "arg2")
```

If you have a slice of arguments, you can use the spread operator

```
args := []string{"-exclude-checks", "arraySyntax,phpdocLint", "-output", "result.txt", "your-path"}
cmd := exec.Command("your-command", args...)
```

To question two: In your code

```
options := " -exclude-checks arraySyntax, PHPDoc"
pathToCode := "C:\\Dev\\PHP\\ResourceSpace_9_0_13357\\include"
    
args := []string{options, pathToCode}
```

you're passing two options to the external program.
If you wrote the same on the command line, you pass

```
your-command.exe " -exclude-checks arraySyntax, PHPDoc" "your-path"
```

This doesn't work, and is also the reason your program doesn't work.

In short, wherever you put a space between in a command, you need to have a separate argument to `exec.Command`. The [example](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Command) also does this.