# exec.command does not execute on windows (golang)

Tags: windows, go, wget

I'm trying to make wget download a file into a temp directory then move it to the appropriate path. I'm trying to use the code below:

```
    // run shell `wget <URL> -O <FILEPATH>`
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd /K wget", url, "-O", "temp/" + filepath, "&& echo Done downloading, moving... '&&' del -y", filename,"'&&' mv temp/", filename, filename)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    return cmd.Run()
}
```

but when called, it doesn't output anything. No errors, nothing.

Comment: The `wget` command is not available on Windows by default.

Comment: My guess is that there's something wrong in your command string. Perhaps you should construct it upfront and print it out to see if it is what you want before running it?

Comment: there are error, you are not checking for them appropriately.

Comment: @icza I have wget installed.

Comment: Thinking a bit outside the box here, but why the heck introduce a dependency on `wget` for something you could *easily* implement in Go?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg It's actually not my script and I don't really write in Go, it's just an option I'm forced to use. I'll explore handling downloading and moving the file in Go. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep this solution (the disadvantages have already been pointed out in the comments) you'll need to separate each argument to `cmd.exe`, so everywhere you would put a space you have a separate argument:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/K", "wget", url, "-O", "temp/" + filepath, "&&", "echo", "Done downloading, moving...", "&&", "del", "-y", filename, "&&", "mv", "temp/" + filename, filename)
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766699) to a similar question

Comment: You may also want to change the second `"temp/" + filename` to `"temp/" + filepath`