# How to use arbitrary "sg_raw " argument in golang?

Tags: go, scsi

I am trying to replicate sg_inq through sg_raw

This is the command used:

inq_cmd := exec.Command("sg_raw", "-r", "512", "/dev/sg0", "12 00 00 00 60 00")

stdoutStderr, err := read_cmd.CombinedOutput()

```
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

fmt.Printf("%s\n", stdoutStderr)

Output after execution is
Inq COMMAND : 
exit status 1
Invalid command byte '12 00 00 00 60 00'

Inquire COMMAND : 
2020/05/28 19:42:48 exit status 1

exit status 1
Invalid command byte '12 00 00 00 60 00'
Usage: sg_raw [OPTION]* DEVICE CDB0 CDB1 ...
Options:
  -b, --binary           Dump data in binary form, even when writing to stdout
  -h, --help             Show this message and exit
  -i, --infile=IFILE     Read data to send from IFILE (default: stdin)
  -k, --skip=LEN         Skip the first LEN bytes when reading data to send
  -n, --nosense          Don't display sense information
  -o, --outfile=OFILE    Write binary data to OFILE (def: hexdump to stdout)
  -r, --request=RLEN     Request up to RLEN bytes of data (data-in)
  -R, --readonly         Open DEVICE read-only (default: read-write)
  -s, --send=SLEN        Send SLEN bytes of data (data-out)
  -t, --timeout=SEC      Timeout in seconds (default: 20)
  -v, --verbose          Increase verbosity
  -V, --version          Show version information and exit

Between 6 and 256 command bytes (two hex digits each) can be specified
and will be sent to DEVICE. Lengths RLEN and SLEN are decimal by
default. Bidirectional commands accepted.

Simple example: Perform INQUIRY on /dev/sg0:
  sg_raw -r 1k /dev/sg0 12 00 00 00 60 00

What's wrong in the command? It would be a great help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the exec error as well as stdout/stderr. You can use [Cmd.CombinedOutput](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput) for a simple way to get both.

Comment: //Doing an Inquire command suing sg_raw . Trying to replicate sg_inq as sg_raw

read_cmd := exec.Command("sg_raw", "-r", "512", "/dev/sg0", "12 00 00 00 60 00") //sudo sg_raw -r 512 /dev/sg0 12 00 00 00 60 00
stdoutStderr, err := read_cmd.CombinedOutput()

    if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
  fmt.Printf("%s\n", stdoutStderr)


Output after execution is
Inquire COMMAND : 
2020/05/28 19:42:48 exit status 1

Comment: Please edit the question to update the code. And show errors and outputs.

Comment: @Marc question edited and error uploaded

Comment: What happens if you run it on the command line? Doesn't look like a go problem.

Comment: I executed the same command (using sg_raw) on command line. I had no issues. SCSI Status returned was (SCSI Status: Good )
I replicated the same thru code. But no idea why error pops up

Comment: I think this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766699): `12 00 00 00 60 00` is interpreted as *one string*, not multiple numbers. If you run it in your shell (without quotes) it works because it splits by space, but if you run it with quotes around the numbers you would probably get the same error output. It might work using `exec.Command("sg_raw", "-r", "512", "/dev/sg0", "12", "00", "00", "00", "60", "00") `

Comment: Thank you Marc and  xarantolus . It worked !!!! Thank you so much.

SCSI Status: Good 

Received 96 bytes of data:
 00     00 00 07